# Java generics: Is there a better solution than Vector2D, Vector3D, Vector4D etc.?

Tags: java, generics, vector

I've a Vector class (not java.util.Vector) for mathematical calculations. At the moment there are subclasses like Vector2D, Vector3D and a protected constructor in Vector which needs the vector's dimension.

Something like that would be nice:

```
Vector<3> 3dVector = new Vector<3>();
```

Of course that is not possible -- at least in Java, maybe C++ templates could handle this.
I've thought about `Vector<C extends Coordinatesystem>` where subclasses of `Coordinatesystem` provide `getDimension()` and can only be instanced as  singletons. But I'm not very happy with that solution. Does anyone has suggestions?

Comment: It is indeed possible in C++.

Comment: and I guess the C++ precompiler would do exactly the same as I do (create classes like Vector2D, Vector3D...)

Comment: Exactly how does Vector2D differ from Vector3D? Can you give some detail?

Comment: Vector2D invokes the superconstructor "Vector(int dimension)" with dimension=2, Vector3D with dimension=3. By this way I can ensure that a vector has a specific dimension (at compile time), e.g. when it is provided to some function.

Answer (score 1):

One of basic Java concepts:

- It should be **simple**, object-oriented, distributed and easy to learn.

That's why Java is missing some C++ stuff, including advanced templates and operator overloading.

In the end you always can write some generic class, like:

```
public class VectorND {
  private double[] coord;

  public VectorND (int n) {
    coord = new double[n];
  }

  public void setCoord(int index, double value) {...}

  public double getCoord(int index) {...} 

  //...  etc  
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `n` member for the dimension, since the information is already available from `coord.length`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're suggesting exactly my current implementation as described. But I don't like something like if (vector.getDimension() != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @unixfan It's Java. It supports static typing only, whic has its pros and cons. Trying to make something more flexible in pure Java most of the times fails for me. Either you start heavily using reflection, which is justified sometimes. Or you try it with an array/map and drop Java safety mechanism by falling back to strings. Mix of those approaches is not available in Java. For good or not - it's not us to decide)

Comment: Yes, but there are better and worse solutions for my problem. My question is not about how good or bad the concepts of Java are, but how it should be done when agreeing on them.

Comment: e.g. is it acceptable to have subclasses like Vector3D which only exist to ensure a dimension of 3 while having a general Vector-class which can handle arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: @unixfan In my opinion it's totally ok to extend *VectorND* to have more specialized *Vector2D*, *Vector3D* and so on. It may affect performance a little, but I suppose if you have heavy-load app, using classes to store vectors is not a good idea anyway.